# Informatica BDM 10.5.3 Multiple File Read

Tags: informatica

I have a task to parse XML file and load data in Data Lake. For that, I have created a flat file PDO and mentioned XML file path into it. Then used Hierarchy_to_Relational transformation to get the file name from the source PDO and parse it. It successfully parsed that one file and load data in target.

**Challange:**

Now, I will have multiple XML file placed on the server. How can I read those files sequentially and load data into target using the same above approach. Please share any alternative method as well

Comment: If my understanding is correct, this should basically work already. Your file listener should pick up the file and Mapping Task be set to Indirect Input File - and that is it!